# How to interpret this surface integral notation from work of Cartan.

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, cartan-geometry

I don't understand the notation for surface integrals used here by E. Cartan in the work *On manifolds with an affine connection*.

Let me quote the passage and how he expresses the form.

Imagine a Cartesian frame attached to each point $\vec{m}$ in space, with $\vec{m}$ as the origin. Let $\vec{e_1}, \vec{e_2}, \vec{e_3}$ be the three vectors which together with $\vec{m}$ define this frame. The number of parameters characterizing the frame can be as large as 12. Let us denote these parameters by $u_i$. Under infinitesimal changes of these parameters $\vec{m}$ as well as $\vec{e_1}, \vec{e_2}, \vec{e_3}$ undergo infinitesimal vectorial variations which can be expressed as linear combinations of $\vec{e_1}, \vec{e_2},  \vec{e_3}$:

$$\eqalign{
d\vec{m} = w^1\vec{e_1} + w^2\vec{e_2} + w^3\vec{e_3} \cr
d\vec{e_1} = w^1_1\vec{e_1} + w^2_1\vec{e_2} + w^3_1\vec{e_3} \cr
d\vec{e_2} = w^1_2\vec{e_1} + w^2_2\vec{e_2} + w^3_2\vec{e_3} \cr
d\vec{e_3} = w^1_3\vec{e_1} + w^2_3\vec{e_2} + w^3_2\vec{e_3} \cr
}$$

The coefficients $w^i$ and $w^i_j$ are linear combinations of the differentials $d\vec{u_i}$. These twelve Pfaffian forms enable one, in effect, to fix the frame at $\vec{m} + d\vec{m}$ in terms of the given frame at $\vec{m}$. These forms $w^i$ and $w^i_j$ are not arbitrary since the integrals:

$$\eqalign{
\int d\vec{m} \cr
\int d\vec{e_i} \cr
}$$
($i = 1, 2, 3$) evaluated along any closed loop are obviously zero. Now, if one transforms these into surface integrals, one obtains:

$$\eqalign{
\int d\vec{m} = \int \int (w^1)'\vec{e_1} + (w^2)'\vec{e_2} + (w^3)'\vec{e_3} + d\vec{e_1}w^1 + d\vec{e_2}w^2 + d\vec{e_3}w^3 
}$$

It is the last notation of the surface integral that is pretty obscure to me.

*I would be happy to add a link to the original PDF but due to copy rights I'm not sure this is allowed.

Comment: You need to provide more context. Where did a surface come from? $d\vec m$ is a $1$-form, so it cannot be integrated over a surface.

Comment: indeed, @TedShifrin it isn't clearly mentioned in the post, but I have the original book, and upon a brief reading it seems that the surface in question is one "enclosed by the loop", and that Cartan is working in $\Bbb{R}^3$ for the moment and simply applying Stokes' theorem (with $\Bbb{R}^3$-valued forms). In his notation, $(\omega^1)'\vec{e_1}$ is what we'd now write $d\omega^1\,\vec{e_1}$, and something like $d\vec{e_1}\,\omega^1$ involves a wedge-product. So, he's integrating $\Bbb{R}^3$-valued 2-forms over a surface whose boundary is the given closed loop.

Comment: btw OP: the reason Cartan is doing this is to derive the structure equations, and here, rather than arguing by integration and Stokes' theorem, and then using arbitrariness o the chosen surface to deduce that the integrand vanishes, you may as well use the fact that $d^2=0$ (essentially equivalent to $\partial^2=0$ in Stokes). So, you can find the structure equations by writing $d(d\vec{m})=0$ and $d(d\vec{e}_i)=0$.

Comment: Also, while we're on the subject of digesting Elie Cartan's work, it should be noted (if I'm remembering correctly) that at the time of writing, he was pretty much making up the notation and ideas for vector-valued differential forms so his notation obviously isn't going to be the modern one. But, if you want, you can try reading parts of the moving frames chapter of *Differential Forms* by Henri Cartan (Elie's son) which was written later, and thus has more 'modern' notation. But of course, it is also fun to read some of the original writings.

Comment: As a Chern student, I am fine with Cartan and vector-valued forms. i missed the application of Stokes’s Theorem. Indeed, the structure equations should come from $d^2=0$, so that surface integral (if the  closed loop bounds) must be $0$ (on arbitrarily small surface patches).  It might be good to read more modern treatments, either Chern, Griffiths, Bryant, or a wonderful new book by Jeanne Clelland on moving frames and surfaces.

Comment: oh I hadn't heard of the book by Clelland. I'll take a look at that and add it to my growing collection of books :)

Comment: Thanks so much guys for the insights! I'll also have a look at these books. It is always difficult go "understand" original notations but I find it gives some added value even to understand the context.